# JAXB generated methods are not using generics

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a JAXB schema where one class contains a list of another class. The schema is given below.

But whenever I create the java classes from this schema , the method is not using generics so I have to use the casts just like pre java 5 way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:common="glodas.research">
    <xs:import namespace="glodas.research" schemaLocation="../common.xsd" />

    <!--  Dashboard Level -->    
    <xs:complexType name="DashboardStatType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="common:IndustryRegionType">
                <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="ModuleStat" type="ModuleStatType"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    <xs:element name="BitsCount" type="BitsCount"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="AgeLimitViolation" type="AgeLimitViolation"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="ModuleViolation" type="ModuleViolation"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                                                        
                </xs:sequence>

                <xs:attribute name="BrCode" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="RegionDescription" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="AverageAgeOfBits" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="NewestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="OldestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="ChapterCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="UnpublishedCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>

            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!--  Module Level -->    

    <xs:complexType name="ModuleStatType">
         <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="ChapterStat" type="ChapterStatType"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    <xs:element name="BitsCount" type="BitsCount"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    <xs:element name="AgeLimitViolation" type="AgeLimitViolation"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />  
                      <xs:element name="ChapterCountViolation" type="ChapterCountViolation"
                            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 

        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ModuleDescription" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="ModuleNumber" type="xs:int" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="AverageAgeOfBits" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="NewestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="OldestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="UnpublishedCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

        <!--  Chapter Level -->    
     <xs:complexType name="ChapterStatType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="BitStat" type="BitStatType" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="BitsCount" type="BitsCount"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="AgeLimitViolation" type="AgeLimitViolation"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>

                <xs:attribute name="ChapterId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="ChapterTitle" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="AverageAgeOfBits" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="NewestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="OldestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!--  Bit Level -->
    <xs:complexType name="BitStatType">
                <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="BitStat" type="BitStatType" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="BitAge" type="BitAge" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                 
                </xs:sequence>

                <xs:attribute name="WiId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="LastPublishedDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>    

   <xs:complexType name="ValidationMessage">
                <xs:attribute name="Text" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Severity" type="xs:int" use="optional"/>
   </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BitAge">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValidationMessage" type="ValidationMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Age" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="BitsCount">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValidationMessage" type="ValidationMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType> 


    <xs:complexType name="AgeLimitViolation">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValidationMessage" type="ValidationMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:complexType name="ChapterCountViolation">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValidationMessage" type="ValidationMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:complexType name="ModuleViolation">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValidationMessage" type="ValidationMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:element name="GetDashboardMonitorResponse">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Response for DashboardMonitor.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="DashboardStatType" name="DashboardStat" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

... The method is generated like this

```
    java.util.List getBitAge();
```

I want the java method to be generated like this

```
java.util.List<BitAge> getBitAge();
```

Comment: maybe you are using java 1.4 when executing jaxb?

Comment: >xjc -version xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6" JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you provide more details about your XML schema?  I have attempted to reproduce you issue with the following

**nov30.xsd**

I made a smaill change to the XML schema you provided since I do not have the source for common.xsd:

```
<!--xs:import namespace="glodas.research" schemaLocation="../common.xsd" / -->

<!--  Dashboard Level -->    
<xs:complexType name="DashboardStatType">
    <!--xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="common:IndustryRegionType"-->
            <xs:sequence> 
                <xs:element name="ModuleStat" type="ModuleStatType"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="BitsCount" type="BitsCount"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="AgeLimitViolation" type="AgeLimitViolation"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="ModuleViolation" type="ModuleViolation"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                                                        
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="BrCode" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="RegionDescription" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="AverageAgeOfBits" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="NewestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="OldestBitDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="ChapterCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="UnpublishedCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>

        <!-- /xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent -->
</xs:complexType>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out nov30.xsd
```

**BitStatType**

The resulting list property still uses generics as expected:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2011.11.30 at 11:38:04 AM EST 
//


package generated;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


/**
 * <p>Java class for BitStatType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="BitStatType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="BitStat" type="{}BitStatType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="BitAge" type="{}BitAge" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="WiId" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="Title" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="LastPublishedDate" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BitStatType", propOrder = {
    "bitStat",
    "bitAge"
})
public class BitStatType {

    @XmlElement(name = "BitStat")
    protected List<BitStatType> bitStat;
    @XmlElement(name = "BitAge")
    protected List<BitAge> bitAge;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "WiId", required = true)
    protected int wiId;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Title", required = true)
    protected String title;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TriggerRulesCount", required = true)
    protected int triggerRulesCount;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TriggerEventsCount", required = true)
    protected int triggerEventsCount;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "LastPublishedDate", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar lastPublishedDate;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the bitStat property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the bitStat property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getBitStat().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link BitStatType }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<BitStatType> getBitStat() {
        if (bitStat == null) {
            bitStat = new ArrayList<BitStatType>();
        }
        return this.bitStat;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the bitAge property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the bitAge property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getBitAge().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link BitAge }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<BitAge> getBitAge() {
        if (bitAge == null) {
            bitAge = new ArrayList<BitAge>();
        }
        return this.bitAge;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the wiId property.
     * 
     */
    public int getWiId() {
        return wiId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the wiId property.
     * 
     */
    public void setWiId(int value) {
        this.wiId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the title property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the title property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTitle(String value) {
        this.title = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the triggerRulesCount property.
     * 
     */
    public int getTriggerRulesCount() {
        return triggerRulesCount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the triggerRulesCount property.
     * 
     */
    public void setTriggerRulesCount(int value) {
        this.triggerRulesCount = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the triggerEventsCount property.
     * 
     */
    public int getTriggerEventsCount() {
        return triggerEventsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the triggerEventsCount property.
     * 
     */
    public void setTriggerEventsCount(int value) {
        this.triggerEventsCount = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lastPublishedDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getLastPublishedDate() {
        return lastPublishedDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lastPublishedDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setLastPublishedDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.lastPublishedDate = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: @java_mouse - I have updated my answer, still not seeing the same issue though.

Comment: >xjc -version
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6"
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)

Comment: Blaise, Could you post what version of XJC version and xjc jars that you are using?

Comment: @java_mouse - I am using the XJC that is included in `Oracle JDK 1.6.0_20-b02`.

Comment: Looks like I am using old version of JAXB